# How Can I View Results Text With Line Breaks in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver, trino

I'm trying to use EXPLAIN on Trino queries in DBeaver.  Even though I have the results set to Text, I only get a single line of text without any line breaks that's truncated at 250 characters.  How can I view the results as multiple lines?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DBeaver always returns a single line of text in text output mode.  Open the value tab by clicking panels on the right side of the results window and you will see all the text returned by your query properly formatted.
[image]